# Setting Grafana domain in Docker container

Tags: docker, grafana

I'm running Grafana from the docker image on docker hub [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/grafana/grafana) (v6.7.4). I would like to add a notification to Microsoft Teams and have the links direct back to the domain I am hosting Grafana on.

I have added the MSTeams webhook to Grafana, and it successfully sends notifications. Now, when I click on "view rule" in the notification, it opens `localhost:3000` since that is the default domain for Grafana.

In trying to configure this to point to `grafana.my.domain`, I have followed [this configuration of the Grafana Docker image](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/installation/configure-docker) as well as looked at the configuration file settings, specifically [the domain and root_url](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/configuration/#domain) settings.

Based on the docker configuration, I have tried passing `GF_SERVER_DOMAIN=grafana.my.domain`, as well as settings for `GF_SERVER_SERVER_FORM_SUB_PATH`, `GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL`, and most combinations of those. I have also attempted to alter a sample.ini file that is shipped with the docker container to include the block:

```
[server]
domain = grafana.my.domain
```

I then mounted the .ini file as `/grafana/config.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini` (based on [this](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/installation/configure-docker/#default-paths)) in my docker-compose file, but it did not pick up on it.

Still, when the notification is clicked on within Teams, I get directed to `localhost:3000`. Am I missing something with the configuration here? It seems passing the environment variable is all that *should* be needed based on the documentation.

Comment: for whoever ends up here as I did: at least in version 8.4.5 GF_SERVER_DOMAIN and GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL are working properly

Comment: Also `docker run -e GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=https://blabla.sub.ai/` worked for me